# Android listview/navigation based app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

How can I create a navigation based app using the android sdk? Not navigating as in using maps, but like how the settings app works. You click on item, and it goes to a new page of items to click.

I can't find any good samples or documentation. Yes, I've looked through the Android developers website.

Answer (score 0):

i think there are two ways.

```
1. 


    yourList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
             Intent in = new Intent();
                in.setClassName("com.example", "com.example.secondScreen");
                startActivity(in);
        }

2.

    yourList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    nextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```